# Rails - How to build a link_to that PUTs to the Controller's update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the controller:

```
class GroupRequestsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @group_request = GroupRequest.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group_request.update_attributes(params[:group_request])
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

In my view I have:

```
<button type="button" class="button positive tiny">Add</button>
<button type="button" class="button tiny">Ignore</button>
```

How can I make those buttons on click, make a remote call to the controller's update method with either add or ignore as the decision param's?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate forms.

```
-form_for :group_request, :remote => true do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :decision, "Add"
  %button{:type => "button", :class => "..."} Add

-form_for :group_request, :remote => true do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :decision, "Ignore"
  %button{:type => "button", :class => "..."} Ignore
```

I use HAML syntax because if you aren't using HAML you should. This is the only consistent way to send values. The Button tag has a "value" attribute, but it isn't supported in all major browsers so you can't rely on it. Unfortunately it means you have to do a bunch of annoying styling to get the buttons to display next to each other.

The only other option I can think of is to use pure JS to make the buttons act like forms, but I can't recommend that because it doesn't degrade gracefully.

Comment: Thanks I'm a little surprised by the form tag idea. Curious is that really the best method? That would be a lot of form tags going on in the page. It's not good to use a remote link?

Comment: You can't really POST data to the server with a link, you can only send data in the query string. There's nothing wrong with having lots of forms on a page. Anchor tags are to GET and DELETE requests what form tags are to POST and PUT requests.